# How to implement correctly IUserType?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, ncommon

I need to create a [custom type](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom) for [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org) by writing a new mapper class that implements `IUserType`. While it is relatively straightforward to override most of the methods and properties, I get some difficulties to understand how to deal correctly with the following members:

- `object Assemble(object cached, object owner);`
- `object DeepCopy(object value);`
- `object Disassemble(object value);`
- `object Replace(object original, object target, object owner);`

I do not understand what is exactly their purpose; and more important, how to properly implement them. Most of the examples I have seen just return the raw input parameter.

```
public object DeepCopy(object value)
{
    return value;
}

public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
{
    return original;
}

public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
{
    return cached;
}

public object Disassemble(object value)
{
    return value;
}
```

**How to implement those methods correctly** in a real case or more complex scenario?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at how Ritesh Rao has done this in his [NCommon](http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon) framework:

The [MoneyUserType](http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/blob/master/NCommon.NHibernate/tests/Domain/MoneyUserType.cs) implements a base class called [CompositeUserTypeBase](http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/blob/master/NCommon.NHibernate/src/CompositeUserTypeBase.cs)

There's more detail in the comments but to summarize:

- DeepCopy - should return a deep copy of the persistent state, stopping at entities and at collections
- Disassemble - transforms the object into its 'cacheable' representation (i.e. associations must be cached as identifier values)
- Assemble - reconstructs an object from the cacheable representation

[It's explained in a lot more detail here](http://web.archive.org/web/20121019101713/http://codeinsanity.com/archive/2009/02/12/using-fluent-nhibernate-in-rhinestone-part-i.aspx)

Comment: The link at then end leads to a very interesting article. Thanks at lot.

Comment: @md1337 Replaced with web.archive

Comment: Fixed archive.org link: http://web.archive.org/web/20121019101713/http://...codeinsanity.com/archive/2009/02/12/using-fluent-nhibernate-in-rhinestone-part-i.aspx

Comment: The link to the web archive is for the wrong article - it's Part I but discussion about implementing `IUserType` is apparently in Part II, which I can't find.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check out this [article](http://blog.miraclespain.com/archive/2008/Mar-18.html). It is a good example of how to implement the IUserType interface.

Comment: The link is broken again but you can find it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150214164507/http://blog.miraclespain.com/archive/2008/Mar-18.html