# How to tell entity framework how to save instances of a custom type (that can be stored as a scalar)

Tags: entity-framework, nodatime

One of my entity classes would be possible to store in a sql server
database as a BIGINT.  My question is: How do I get a Entity Framework
context to know how to store and retrieve instances of my entity class?

More detail.  I'm using [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/), which can represent a (much) wider range of
dates than can SQL or .NET datetime (AND it's a dessert topping).  My Entity Class, Happening, is a wrapper around NodaTime's 
Instant class.  I can set a Happening from a long, and get a long from
a happening with methods like .SetFromLong(long instant) and .ToLong().

Currently I have my model working, saving classes that contain
properties of the dot net DateTime type.  If instead I want to use properties
of my custom type "Happening", how do I tell Entity Framework how to save those?

If I'm reading this article about Modeling and Mapping am I on the
right track or missing something simpler?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896343.aspx

I'm using entity framework 4.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820915/entity-framework-custom-data-type-mapping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What i recommend doing is adding 2 properties on your entity a NodaTime and a long, and exclude your NodaTime property using [NotMapped] in your EF model, then in your getter/setter update the long.

ie

```
public class MyEntity{
   public long TimeAsLong{get;set;}
   [NotMapped]
   public Happening {
      get{
        return new Happening().SetFromLong(TimeAsLong);
      }
      set {
         TimeAsLong = value.ToLong();
      }
   }
}
```

The effect of this will be that the long is stored in the db but you can access it on the class via NodaTime

Comment: That worked, thank you.  I have no need for TimeAsLong except to accommodate EF, does that come up much, and (in your experience) do you try to name those members distinctively, TimeAsLongForEF, anything like that?

Comment: Its all about storage vs presentation, sometimes its better/more efficient to store something in a different from how you want to use it, this is one example. There aren't actually heaps of places ive found where i need to do this but it does happen on occasion, another example ive found is storing a single Char in the database requires converting it to a string in your write model (EF doesnt distinguish between varchar[1] and varchar[2]they are both string). Personally i wouldnt label the field as EF but thats just a preference thing.

Comment: Also note that EF doesn't really care if the propery is public or not (if you happen to use Code First). Although you still need some way to map it even if it is private. What we did, we put the EF configuration class in the entity class so it can access the private fields as well and do the mapping. The drawback is that you have mapping class in your entity which you may or may not have a problem.