# NHibernate, trying to store an object as a string in DB

Tags: nhibernate

What I'm trying to achieve is to serialize in some form an object and store it in the db and then recreate it.

This is the structure: I'm using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators for conversion

```
 public class Order : AggregateRoot
 {
    private string _cityList;
    public virtual CityList CityList { get => (CityList)_cityList; }
 }

 public class CityList : ValueObject
 {
     private string _cities { get; }

     public CityList(string cities)
     {
         _cities = cities;
     }

     public static explicit operator CityList(string cityList)
     {
         return new CityList(cityList);
     }

     public static implicit operator string(CityList cityList)
     {
         return (string)cityList;
     }
  }
```

This is the configuration

```
 mapping
        .Map(Reveal.Member<Order>("CityList"))
        .CustomType("string")
        .Column("CityList");
```

This is what I get

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type CityList to type System.String
>
> NHibernate.Type.AbstractStringType.Set(DbCommand cmd, object value, int index, ISessionImplementor session)PropertyValueException:
>   Error dehydrating property value for CityList
>   Command.Stack.Adapters.Base.UnitOfWork.IUnitOfWork.CommitAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

Why do I get this? and how to solve it ?

Comment: I couldn't get your `CityList` --> `string` operator to work in isolation. I had to change it to: `return cityList._cities;` to get it to work. Although, the exception I got was `StackOverflowException` not `InvalidCastException`. It's worth looking at though as the NH code that throws the exception does this: `if (parameter.Size > 0 && ((string)value).Length > parameter.Size)`, so the cast needs to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear this is not the exact answer to your question but want to give alternate way to achieve the same. We created Custom IUserType called JsonMappable Type. This type serializes and deserialized the data saved into DB as JSON string, you need to override NullSafeGet and Set, then its easy to map it like this in the mapping file,

```
        Property(p => p.UserAvailability, m =>
        {
            m.Type<JsonMappableType<UserAvailability>>();
        });
```

This link provides how to implement iusertype

[How to implement correctly IUserType?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565056/how-to-implement-correctly-iusertype)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IUserType interface.

```
[Serializable]
public class AsClobStringUserType<T> : IUserType
{
    public AsClobStringUserType()
    {
        
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The type returned by NullSafeGet()
    /// </summary>
    Type IUserType.ReturnedType => typeof(T);
    bool IUserType.IsMutable => false;
    SqlType[] IUserType.SqlTypes => new SqlType[] { new StringClobSqlType() };

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for casching, the object is immutable, just return 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cached"></param>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    object IUserType.Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return cached;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deep copy the Translation by creating a new instance with the same contents
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    object IUserType.DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        if (value.GetType() != typeof(T)) return null;

        string jsonString = JsonSerializationService.Instance.Serialize((T)value);

        return JsonSerializationService.Instance.Deserialize<T>(jsonString);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for casching, the object is immutable, just return 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    object IUserType.Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use json string to check the equality
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="object1"></param>
    /// <param name="object2"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool IUserType.Equals(object object1, object object2)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(object1, null) && ReferenceEquals(object2, null)) return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(object1, null) || ReferenceEquals(object2, null)) return false;

        return JsonSerializationService.Instance.Serialize((T)object1) == JsonSerializationService.Instance.Serialize((T)object2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="object"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    int IUserType.GetHashCode(object @object)
    {
        if (@object != null && @object.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            return JsonSerializationService.Instance.Serialize((T)@object).GetHashCode();
        }

        return @object.GetHashCode();
    }

    #region Serialization
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve an instance of the mapped class from.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Should handle possibility of null values.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="owner">the entity to work with. (serialized object)</param>
    object IUserType.NullSafeGet(DbDataReader rs, string[] names, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        /// => Translation should be stored in single column 
        if (names.Length != 1) throw new InvalidOperationException("Translation should be stored in single column.");

        string value = rs[names[0]] as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return JsonSerializationService.Instance.Deserialize<T>(value);

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write an instance of the mapped class to a prepared statement.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Should handle possibility of null values.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="cmd">the object to be serialized and written to persistence store.</param>
    /// <param name="value">the object to be serialized and written to persistence store.</param>
    void IUserType.NullSafeSet(DbCommand cmd, object value, int index, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        DbParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters[index];

        if (value == null)
        {
            parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            parameter.Value = JsonSerializationService.Instance.Serialize(value);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary> 
    /// As our object is immutable just return the original
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="original"></param>
    /// <param name="target"></param>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    object IUserType.Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }
}
```